# The strange behavior with the installation fileset of devices.ethernet.mlx.rte?

Tags: files, aix

1) What mean about the warnings "0454-066 Cannot update traceid 66C0 to an earlier version."
2) What ever about the fileset of devices.ethernet.mlx.rte 7.99.1.0 that does not exist at all?

```
#
#
#installp -acgXYvd /aix71_0304 devices.ethernet.mlx.rte 
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                    Pre-installation Verification...
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Verifying selections...done
Verifying requisites...done
Results...

WARNINGS
--------
  Problems described in this section are not likely to be the source of any
  immediate or serious failures, but further actions may be necessary or
  desired.

  Missing Requisites of Previously Installed Software
  ---------------------------------------------------
  The following fileset updates are requisites of software that is already
  installed.  They are not currently installed but should be to ensure that
  the system functions correctly.  These updates are not on the current
  installation media.

    devices.ethernet.mlx.rte 7.99.1.0         # Fileset Update

  << End of Warning Section >>

SUCCESSES
---------
  Filesets listed in this section passed pre-installation verification
  and will be installed.

  Selected Filesets
  -----------------
  devices.ethernet.mlx.rte 7.1.3.30           # RoCE Converged Network Adapter 

  << End of Success Section >>

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                   BUILDDATE Verification ...
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Verifying build dates...done
FILESET STATISTICS 
------------------
    1  Selected to be installed, of which:
        1  Passed pre-installation verification
  ----
    1  Total to be installed

0503-409 installp:  bosboot verification starting...
installp:  bosboot verification completed.
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                         Installing Software...
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+

installp:  APPLYING software for:
        devices.ethernet.mlx.rte 7.1.3.30


. . . . . << Copyright notice for devices.ethernet.mlx >> . . . . . . .
 Licensed Materials - Property of IBM

 5765H4000
   Copyright International Business Machines Corp. 2012, 2014.

 All rights reserved.
 US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or disclosure
 restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
. . . . . << End of copyright notice for devices.ethernet.mlx >>. . . . 

0454-066 Cannot update traceid 66C0 to an earlier version.
         1.1 vs. 1.0.
0454-066 Cannot update traceid 6700 to an earlier version.
         1.1 vs. 1.0.
Finished processing all filesets.  (Total time:  15 secs).

lppchk:  The following filesets need to be installed or corrected to bring
         the system to a consistent state:

  devices.ethernet.mlx.rte 7.99.1.0       (not installed; requisite fileset)

0503-409 installp:  bosboot verification starting...
installp:  bosboot verification completed.
0503-408 installp:  bosboot process starting...

bosboot: Boot image is 51228 512 byte blocks.
0503-292 This update will not fully take effect until after a
        system reboot.

    * * *  A T T E N T I O N  * * *
    System boot image has been updated. You should reboot the
    system as soon as possible to properly integrate the changes
    and to avoid disruption of current functionality.

installp:  bosboot process completed.
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                                Summaries:
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Installation Summary
--------------------
Name                        Level           Part        Event       Result
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
devices.ethernet.mlx.rte    7.1.3.30        USR         APPLY       SUCCESS    
devices.ethernet.mlx.rte    7.1.3.30        ROOT        APPLY       SUCCESS    

installp:  * * *  A T T E N T I O N ! ! ! 
        Software changes processed during this session require this system 
        and any of its diskless/dataless clients to be rebooted in order 
        for the changes to be made effective.
#
#
#
#lppchk -v                                              
lppchk:  The following filesets need to be installed or corrected to bring
         the system to a consistent state:

  devices.ethernet.mlx.rte 7.99.1.0       (not installed; requisite fileset)

#
#
#
#oslevel -s                                             
7100-03-04-1441
#
#
#
#lslpp -l  devices.ethernet.mlx.rte                     
  Fileset                      Level  State      Description         
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Path: /usr/lib/objrepos
  devices.ethernet.mlx.rte  7.1.3.30  COMMITTED  RoCE Converged Network Adapter

Path: /etc/objrepos
  devices.ethernet.mlx.rte  7.1.3.30  COMMITTED  RoCE Converged Network Adapter
#
```

Comment: You may want to use a more current techlevel. The package you're referring to is from TL3 SP4 which is now 5 years old. Apart from that there are multiple APARs on that fileset, e.g. IV65506 or IV92065
Apart from that, why do you think the traceid messages are warnings?
Regarding the requisite fileset version issue, that is either a packaging bug or an error in the .toc file in the folder from where you installed that package from.

Comment: It  seems to be a "big"  bug  because of the unknown release for 99！